# Symfony LDAP bind as current user

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony-security

So i have Symfony 4 app which should allow login via LDAP and based on your groups modify some of the values in this ldap directory.

The Login itselfs, and mapping from Ldap Groups to `ROLE_` works perfectly.

The idea was that only the currently logedin user does a modification. Not a hidden `Directory Admin`. 
For this i would need to `$ldap->bind()` with the user credentials each time a loged in user wants to modify the directory.

But for this i would need the password. The only way i could think of, would be to save the password in the session - but form a security standpoint this would be a very very bad idea.

Is there any other way? Like store the already binded connection somehow? 
As far as I see in the Symfony security component - the UserProvider only refreshes the user from sesison - without calling ldap again.
The `LdapBindAuthenticationProvider` only uses the `->bind()` call with the given credentials and catches an exception if password doesnt match.
But the connection itself is a simple fire & forget.